# Can I obtain the web browsing history from in-app browsers on iOS and iPadOS?

Tags: ios, safari, ipados, browser-history

Every week or two I recap my Safari web browsing history, which is synced in iCloud for all my Apple devices.

However, on iOS/iPadOS, web links usually open first in the in-app web browser.

Is there a way to obtain these in-app browser histories?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I suspected it wouldn’t be possible. Would you mind adding a bit about router logging as per the second question in the final paragraph of my question?

Comment: That would depend on the router manufacturer and firmware version.  In addition, if a router is flashed with an alternative firmware, such as DD-WRT, the answer would be different.  In keeping with the guidelines of this site, I would recommend you ask that in a seperate question so you can include all the relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently (as of iOS 14) no way to view browser history if it's done within an app.  Developers use Apple's SFSafariViewController class and it doesn't expose this option to developers.

In addition to not being able to view history, in-app browsers can't provide access to autofill data or website data.

Comment: How about if you have MDM, can you install one to see the history there?